# Is there anything I need to add to make the button open another JFrame/GUI

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, actionlistener

When I pressed the button to open my Display GUI which is in another class it doesn't open it until I press a different button.

Note: What the program does is write information into a MS access table the display button opens a new GUI to display what are the information written in the MS access table.

I tried removing the Thread but that just freezes the GUI.

```
//b3=button 3. f=JFrame

    b3.addActionListener(new ActionListener () 
    {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
        {
            Thread th=new Thread()
            {   
                public void run ()
                {
                    new Display();
                    f.dispose();
                }
                };
            th.start();
        }
    });
```

Comment: why do you need another thread just to open a second screen?

Comment: Well I was searching online for possible solutions about JFrame freezing and this is what I found so I tried it. my initial code doesn't include adding a new thread.

Comment: Your ui is freezing cause something is blocking the EDT thread when you call the constructor of your 'Display' class (i guess the write operation to the MS access table => this must be executed in a seperate thread).

Comment: @KAliert how do I do that? sorry for the silly question I am completely new to programming on using MS access as the DB

Comment: No problem. Can you post the code from your Display class? At least the code which gets executed when you call the constructor.

Comment: *"another JFrame"* 1) See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556) 2) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).